# GridView paging not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I'm starting on vb.net and I have to make a GridView that shows registers from an sql query with paging enabled on the GridView. But the paging only works for the first registers in page 1, when I click page 2 it shows less registers than it should and the bar with the page numbers dissapears.

I've seen people with a similar problem, all that's said is to put:

```
 Protected Sub GridView2_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView2.PageIndexChanging
    GridView2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView2.DataBind()
End Sub
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

Here are the codes that fill the GridView with two possible queries. If I disable paging, they work just fine, so the problem is not on the queries:

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim command As String
    command = "SELECT [GVA14]. [COD_CLIENT] As Codigo, [GVA14].[RAZON_SOCI] As Nombre,tabla.[periodo] As Cuota FROM [GVA14] LEFT JOIN (SELECT cod_client as cod_client ,MAX(periodo) as periodo FROM emCuotas GROUP BY cod_client) As tabla ON ([GVA14]. [COD_CLIENT] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT=tabla.[cod_client] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) ORDER BY [GVA14].[COD_CLIENT]"
    Dim dTable As New DataTable
    Dim dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(command, con)

    dataAdapter.Fill(dTable)
    GridView2.DataSource = dTable
    GridView2.DataBind()
    nro = 1

End Sub

 Protected Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim f1 As String
    f1 = TextBox1.Text
    Dim f2 As String
    f2 = TextBox2.Text
    Dim command As String
    Dim cuantos As Integer = 50
    Dim inicio As Integer=0
    command = "SELECT COD_CLIENT,RAZON_SOCI,FECHA_ALTA FROM GVA14 WHERE FECHA_ALTA BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'" & f1 & "',103) AND CONVERT(datetime,'" & f2 & "',103) Order By COD_CLIENT,FECHA_ALTA"
    Dim dTable As New DataTable
    Dim dataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(command, con)
    dataAdapter.Fill(dTable)
    GridView2.DataSource = dTable
    GridView2.DataBind()
    command = "SELECT Count(FECHA_ALTA) FROM GVA14 WHERE FECHA_ALTA BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime,'" & f1 & "',103) AND CONVERT(datetime,'" & f2 & "',103)"
    Dim comand As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(command, con)

    Label1.Text = comand.ExecuteScalar
    nro=2

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did...

```
    Protected Sub gvExistingICByUser_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles gvExistingICByUser.PageIndexChanging
       Dim grid As GridView = DirectCast(sender, GridView)
       GetExistingICByUser(CurrentUser)
       grid.DataSource = dtExistingICByUser
       grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
       grid.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Line breakdown inside the PageIndexChanging event....
1) cast ur gridview as a grideview. (i'm not sure exactly y its done this way, but it works w/ it and not w/o)

2)LOAD YOUR GRID VIEW (i did this in another function that returns a data table)

3)Set the page index

4)Bind

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines of code

```
GridView2.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
GridView2.DataBind()
```

and just specify `GridView.PageSize` (and allow paging, of course)

Comment: Done that, and it does not work either, it just shows the first page and the index doesnt change.